# when does view controller triggers its predecessor viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a 3 views storyboard (on xcode 5), I finished my first 2 views (It is a form) and the last view should be the result of the form (data should be saved to an array and print the view)

For some reason, the first view controller "viewDidLoad" fires only on the first view controller and on the third, but not on the second.

any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Views / view controllers? Probably want to add a screenshot of your storyboard and the class definitions.

Comment: First of all, when I say views I mean view controllers, 

About the code, the class is a generic class, i did not modify anything there, just a generic "Objective-C class" with "trageted for ipad" checked and is subclass of the first class.

Comment: Iv'e found out the issue, so I edited my question.

Comment: @izzy Set a brakpoint at [super viewDidLoad];, then you will see where the methode is triggered. If you have 3 ViewControllers, you have to greate 3 UIViewController files, then you need to assign the UIViewConontroller file to your ViewController in your StoryBoard, then you have to pass the value to the ViewController you like to display the array in.

Comment: Ok the issue was I made one form inherit the other, and the one that did not trigger the function was inheriting UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was I made one form inherit the other, and the one that did not trigger the function was inheriting UIViewController